# Invisible jump to the main menu from a function - can anyone spot the error?

Tags: python, function

I have the following code in which a bewildering jump back to line 48 in the login function from the quiz1() function occurs. The code seems fine and cannot find the source or cause for the error as there is no reason for it to go back!

**The full code** with file can be tested and found here:

https://repl.it/KdEI/2

**Test data:**

```
username: admin
password: admin123

Press 1 to play
Press 1 to go to Quiz

>>ERROR (Jumps back to the main menu, and specifically to line 48 in the login function
```

**Comment**

I'm assuming the error lies somewhere in the login code. To **award an answer** I would like:

1. The error spotted and explained
2. Comments on more elegant ways of solving the login (username and password read from file) <-- Currently the set up for "invalid username or password" doesn't quite work properly either.

**Login Function code:**

```
def login():
  print("===Login===")
  username=input("Enter username:")
  password=input("Enter password:")
  with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    username_correct=False
    password_correct=False
    while username_correct==False and password_correct==False:      
      for row in reader:
          for field in row:
            if field==username:
              currentindex=row.index(field)
              if row[currentindex+1]==password:
                print("****You're in!*****")
                username_correct=True
                password_correct=True
                print()
                f.close()
                mainmenu()
              else:
                break

      print("Wrong username or password, sorry!")
      welcomemenu()
```

**Update:**

This seems to work, by removing the call to main menu from the while loop. However, the code needs restructuring for elegance and the best way to output the "invalid combination or user details" if the user gets it wrong:

```
def login():
  print("===Login===")
  passwordC=False
  usernameC=False

  while passwordC==False and usernameC==False:    
      username=input("Enter username:")
      password=input("Enter password:")
      with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)

        for row in reader:
          for field in row:          
           if field==username and row[1]==password:
             passwordC=True
             usernameC=True


  if passwordC==True and usernameC==True:
    print("**You're in**")
    mainmenu()
  else:
    print("Try again - wrong username and password")
    login()
```

Comment: I think you should use a database (perhaps sqlite if this would be a light app) for username and password storage.

Comment: I don't want to use a database. This is for teaching and learning purposes and needs to be solved as-is

Comment: Is it fixed now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Executing `mainmenu` within the loop is your error.
Try:

```
def login():
    print("===Login===")
    username=input("Enter username:")
    password=input("Enter password:")
    with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)
        username_correct=False
        password_correct=False
        for row in reader:
            for field in row:
                if field==username:
                    currentindex=row.index(field)
                    if row[currentindex+1]==password:
                        username_correct=True
                        password_correct=True
    if password_correct == False or username_correct == False:
        print("Wrong username or password, sorry!")
        welcomemenu()
    print("****You're in!*****")
    mainmenu()
```

As the program is not complete, you need to exit

```
def quiz1():
    print("===Quiz1===")
    print("Question 1:")
    exit()
```

Comment: https://repl.it/KdEI/4    ...this is the link with your solution in the login function. It APPEARS to work, but test it with this: First get the username and password WRONG, then go through again and go to the quiz function = you'll see it returns to the login function again...! Any thoughts?

Comment: I see what you're saying but the problem is still not fixed completely .....exit() simply closes the whole program and forces quit. I just want it to stop at the command prompt?

Comment: You can run the script in `interactive mode` with the `-i` (minus eye) option on the command line but I don't see to what end. By the way, stripping awarded reputation points and adding further requirements to an existing question, is frowned upon. You can of course accept another answer, if it is a better fit for your question. If that is the case I encourage you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need of `usernameC` and `passwordC`:

```
def login():
  print("===Login===")

  while True:    
      username=input("Enter username:")
      password=input("Enter password:")
      with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
        reader=csv.reader(f)

        for row in reader:
          for field in row:          
           if field==username and row[1]==password:
               mainmenu()
               break
      print("Try again - wrong username and password")
```

This should fix things.

If you want to use `pickle` as I've described below, the function definition would look like the following (much simpler):

```
with open("userdata.pkl", "rb") as f:
    userdata = pickle.load(f)

def login():
  print("===Login===")
  while True:    
      username=input("Enter username:")
      password=input("Enter password:")

      if username in userdata:
          if userdata[username] == password:  # Checks the password.
               mainmenu()
               break
      print("Try again - wrong username and password")
```

Also, I would like to point out that storing passwords in a text file is a bad idea, even for learning purposes. If you don't want to use a database, use binary files instead to store the usernames and passwords. Use a routine like the following:

```
import pickle

data = {"user1": "password1", "user2": "password2"}  # dictionary would be the data structure of the choice for this case.
with open("userdata.pkl", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(data, f)
```

Later, you can retrieve the dictionary as follows:

```
with open("userdata.pkl", "rb") as f:
    userdata = pickle.load(f)
```

Now, `print(userdata)` would give: `{"user1": "password1", "user2": "password2"}`

Comment: This is a useful post, thanks. If you're able to analyse the code for the strange bug, I can accept your answer. Could you also edit your pickled answer to include the username and password search specifically

Comment: See Update: this seems to work ...(in terms of the loop coming out) but it still doesn't say "invalid" if the combination is wrong:

Comment: Sam Chats - thanks, BUT similar to Rolf of Saxony's answer, it appears to work but not on further testing. Try this (it has your code in the login function) https://repl.it/KdEI/5   ....first get the username and password wrong, and then proceed to get it right and to the Play and Quiz functions. You'll notice the second time around it still erroneously returns to the login function! Why?

Comment: Also you have got a call to main menu inside the whileloop and got rid of the flags. I don't think that is ideal?

Comment: repl.it/KdEI/4 Rolf of Saxony's solution seems closest, but still doesn't work when you first get the username and password wrong on the first try. then go through with admin and admin123 and you'll notice the error ...it returns from the quiz1 function to lie 53 in the login function

Answer (score 0):

I found what I think is the error.

```
  for row in reader:
      for field in row:
        if field==username:
          currentindex=row.index(field)
          if row[currentindex+1]==password:
            print("****You're in!*****")
            username_correct=True
            password_correct=True
            print()
            f.close()
            mainmenu()
          else:
            break
```

After the user logs in you close the file. Then you call the mainmenu function. After you return from the main menu function you continue your for loop onto the next row of the file... but you closed that file already... Thus error.

Try this out see if it works (no need for csv reader)

```
def login():
  print("===Login===")
  username=input("Enter username:")
  password=input("Enter password:")
  with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
    authenticated = False
    line = f.readline().strip()
    while authenticated ==False and line != "":
        values = line.split(",")
        if len(values) >= 2 and values[0] == username and values[1] == password:
            authenticated=True
        line = f.readline().strip()
    if authenticated:
        print("****You're in!*****")
        mainmenu()
    else:
        print("Wrong username or password, sorry!")
        welcomemenu()
```

Comment: Thanks you neh. If you are able to have a look at the link, it'll show you that even if you remove f.close(), the error (jump back to line 48) persists.

Comment: See update - main menu call removed from the while loop which helps. still needs fixing.

Comment: this is because you have two loops when you need one... your second loops is not needed. Instead of checking each field of the row (0 through 4) just check row[0] and row[1]

Comment: I will add the more elegant solution see if it helps... Let me know if it doesnt.

Comment: Thanks neh - but I'm trying to fix the existing solution. This is Sam Chat's solution - see the thread above for my comments. It appears to work, but doesn't if you FIRST get the username and password wrong. https://repl.it/KdEI/5. Also he has got a call to main menu inside the whileloop and got rid of the flags. I don't think that is ideal?

Comment: https://repl.it/KdEI/4  Rolf of Saxony's solution seems closest, but still doesn't work when you first get the username and password wrong on the first try. then go through with admin and admin123 and you'll notice the error ...it returns from the quiz1 function to lie 53 in the login function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you've solved this or not, but the original problem is that list.index doesn't do what you think it does - it doesn't give the index of the current item, but searches for a matching item and gives that index. So, for example:

```
row = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
print(row[4], row.index(row[4]))
```

prints `1 0`, not `1 4`. Your userinfo file contains two fields containing 'admin', so you'll get two matches with the password.

The best way to get the index of the current field is to use `enumerate`.

```
for currentindex, field in enumerate(row):
```

Rewriting the login() function so it's a bit more readable, I think you intend to do something like the following:

```
def is_valid_user(username, password):
  with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
      if row[0] == username and row[1] == password:
        return True
  return False

def login():
  print("===Login===")
  username=input("Enter username:")
  password=input("Enter password:")
  if is_valid_user(username, password):
    mainmenu()
  else:
    print("Wrong username or password, sorry!")
    welcomemenu()
```

There's also a problem with the way that you call the next function from the current one. *e.g.*, if you repeatedly enter the wrong password, you get the following chain of function calls:

```
main -> welcomemenu -> login -> welcomemenu -> login -> welcomemenu ->
  login -> welcomemenu -> login -> welcomemenu -> login -> welcomemenu ->
  login -> welcomemenu -> login -> welcomemenu -> login -> welcomemenu etc
```

Sooner or later, this pattern will cause you a problem. Instead, try to arrange the function calls to 'fan out', something like the following:

```
def welcomemenu():
  while True:
    print("""
      =========*WELCOME MENU*===========
      1. Register               
      2. Login
      3. Quit

      *You need to register and login for access to the game menu
      """)
    userselection=int(input("Enter Selection"))
    if userselection==1:
      register()
    elif userselection==2:
      if login():
        mainmenu()
        break
    elif userselection==3:
      break

def is_valid_user(username, password):
  with open('userinfo.txt','r') as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
      if row[0] == username and row[1] == password:
        return True
  return False

def login():
  print("===Login===")
  username=input("Enter username:")
  password=input("Enter password:")
  valid = is_valid_user(username, password)
  if not valid:
    print("Wrong username or password, sorry!")
  return valid
```

so the 'wrong password' sequence will now go:

`main -> welcomemenu -> login (back) -> login (back) -> login (back) etc`